# Open parts of CSV in Stata

Tags: csv, import, stata

I'd like to know more about how Stata 13 can work with dataset in .CSV of large size (let's say higher than the RAM I have).

I can open the first nth line or the first nth columns with the following command

```
import delimited using filename.csv, rowrange(1:1000) colrange(1:3)
```

However, it seems I cannot  open, without loading the whole dataset first, one of the following things:

1. the first and last three variables
2. the first and last 100 lines
3. a list of lines such that a variable satisfies some condition

Are there ways to do these things in Stata?

Comment: Not that I know of. My usual strategy for large text files is to use `chunky` from SSC, or use the usual UNIX tools to preprocess the files, or to use `import delimited` in a loop and then concatenate the files.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Chunky looks useful. I also use unix tools such as awk - but I like when my programs can be directly understood and used by windows users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do this with one command, but you can try importing by parts and using `merge`. An example:

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example data -----

copy http://www.stata.com/examples/auto.csv auto.csv, replace

*----- what you want -----

* import first two columns
import delimited using "auto.csv", colrange(1:2) rowrange(1:6)
gen obs = _n

* save in temp file
tempfile first
save "`first'"

* import last two columns
import delimited using "auto.csv", colrange(4:5) rowrange(1:6) clear
gen obs = _n

* merge current data with the tempfile
merge 1:1 obs using "`first'", assert(match) nogen

* list
drop obs
order make foreign price
list
```

The previous covers point **1** in your question. For point **2**, do something similar but instead of `merge`, use `append`.

The commands `infile` and `use` both support the use of `if` and `in` in their syntax, which may help you with point **3**.

### Edit

An example for point **2**:

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example data -----

copy http://www.stata.com/examples/auto.csv auto.csv, replace

*----- what you want -----

* import first two rows of data
import delimited using "auto.csv", colrange(1:4) rowrange(2:3)

* save in temp file
tempfile first
save "`first'"

* import last two rows of data
import delimited using "auto.csv", colrange(1:4) rowrange(10:11) clear

* append current data with the tempfile
append using "`first'"

* list
sort make
list
```

Observation 1 starts in row 2 (row 1 contains variable names), so we need to shift everything in `rowrange()` by 1. Curiously, some testing shows that adding the `varnames(1)` option did nothing to change this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks! I guess for point 2, one would need to add the option varnames(1) when extracting the last 100 lines, so that variables are similarly named in each part.

Comment: You're welcome. No. There is no need to add `varnames()` to ensure that variables are similarly named in both parts. You will get the same variables for each part iff you use the exact same data source (e.g. **auto.csv**) and `colrange()` is specified in the same way for each call to `import delimited`. I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: Also, consider upvoting/accepting answers to your questions. This will also increase your reputation. You can read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the two comments.